# How to edit sub properties of elements css in Chrome dev tool for border properties?

Tags: google-chrome

This is hard to explain so attaching an image.

When creating css on the fly, you can't edit the sub properties, is there a way to do that? [image]

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] ok found and easy solution, I simply copy the sub code, then disable or delete parent, then paste it in , works fine;)